# How do you get the text from an HTML 'datacell' using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to strip out some data from HTML files. I have the logic coded to get the right cells.  Now I am struggling to get the actual contents of the 'cell':

here is my HTML snippet:

headerRows[0][10].contents

```
  [<font size="+0"><font face="serif" size="1"><b>Apples Produced</b><font size="3">       
  </font></font></font>]
```

Note that this is a list item from Python [].

I need the value Apples Produced but can't get to it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Suggestions on a good book that explains this would earn my eternal gratitude

---

Thanks for that answer.  However-isn't there a more general answer. What happens if my cell doesn't have a bold attribute

say it is:

```
 [<font size="+0"><font face="serif" size="1"><I>Apples Produced</I><font size="3">       
  </font></font></font>]
```

*Apples Produced*

I am trying to learn to read/understand the documentation and your response will help

I really appreciate this help. The best thing about these answers is that it is a lot easier to generalize from them then I have been able to do so from the BeautifulSoup documentation. I learned to program in the Fortran era and now I am learning python and I am amazed at its power - BeautifulSoup is an example. Making a coherent whole of the documentation is tough for me.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
headerRows[0][10].contents[0].find('b').string
```

Answer (score 5):

The [BeautifulSoup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html) should cover everything you need - in this case it looks like you want to use `findNext`:

```
headerRows[0][10].findNext('b').string
```

A more generic solution which doesn't rely on the `<b>` tag would be to use the [text](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#arg-text) argument to `findAll`, which allows you to search only for `NavigableString` objects:

```
>>> s = BeautifulSoup(u'<p>Test 1 <span>More</span> Test 2</p>')
>>> u''.join([s.string for s in s.findAll(text=True)])
u'Test 1 More Test 2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a base class that I extend all Beautiful Soup classes with a bunch of methods that help me get at text within a group of elements that I don't necessarily want to rely on the structure of. One of those methods is the following:

```
  def clean(self, val):
    if type(val) is not StringType: val = str(val)
    val = re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', s) #remove tags
    val = re.sub("\s+" , " ", val) #collapse internal whitespace
    return val.strip() #remove leading & trailing whitespace
```